# Phone state listener using broadcast receiver in android not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-logcat, phone-state-listener

I am trying to detect Incoming call using `Broadcast Listener`.Since I received one fault in my app when someone calls, my app still plays the song. So I want to pause song during Incoming Call. But I am not receiving any response.

Here is the complete `code` So that you all can understand where am I messing.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCall">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**IncomingCall.java**

```
package com.example.suraj.freewee;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        this.context = context;
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "inside on receive");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
    }


}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Number : " + incomingNumber);
        try {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
                    //PAUSE
                    SongsAdapter.player.pause();
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "call ringing");
                    break;
                }
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {
                    SongsAdapter.player.pause();
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "call offhook");
                    break;
                }
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: {
                    //PLAY
                    SongsAdapter.player.start();
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "call idle");
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

In `logcat` no log errors are shown
So why is this giving me such behaviour. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any answers?

Answer (score 2):

You're registering listener inside `onReceive`. That's pointless. As 
Android documentation states:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.

It should be enough to get `EXTRA_STATE` from `Intent` in `onReceive` and do your `switch` there.

If you're still not getting anything logged trim it to minimal case - leave only `Log` statement inside `onReceive`. Does it work? AFAIK there are two cases when app won't receive broadcast - If it was never started or if it was force stopped.

Comment: Can you answer this question?, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63227315/5359340 is there any way to solve this question

Answer (score 0):

try editing onReceive() as below

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)    
{
    TelephonyManager phoneManager =
        (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    if(phoneManager.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) 
    {
        string fromNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.i(TAG, "u have a call from a number " + fromNumber);
    }
}
```

Now call to ur number and see the number in logs

Comment: Nothing comes in log cat.

Comment: try with these 2 statements u will have a log remove every thing in onReceive() method.
String newPhoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

  if(newPhoneState .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING){Log.i("calling","u have a call");}