# How can I make this phone call states Broadcast receiver to work all the times?(non-stops)

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, background-service, phone-state-listener

I'm creating an application, which will show toast messages before and after the call states. I generated and installed my application on my mobile. **it was working well after a few days or sometimes a few hours.** but after that, it's stopped, in order to run the application I need to open the application again. how can I modify my application to work very well? Thank you

> manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- This part is inside the application -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> MainActivity.class

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       checkAndRequestPermissions();

      }
    private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
 int readPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
 int read_call_log = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);

 List listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

 if (readPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
 }

 if (read_call_log != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
 }

 if (read_call_log != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS);
 }

 if (read_call_log != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
 }

 if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
             (String[]) listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
             REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);

     return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

> CallReciver.class

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            try {

                runfirstTime(context,intent);
                Toast.makeText(context, "1st", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New versions of Android does not allow you to do what you are trying to achieve, unless you create foreground service.

Android does not want apps to run in background without explicit knowledge of the user.

So you need to create a foreground service and show a persistent notification in notification panel. Then you can create a BroadcastReceiver from the Foreground Service.

Launch your service as a foreground service using the code below

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   context.startForegroundService(intent);
}
else {
   context.startService(intent); 
}
```

And in service onCreate() make something like that:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   startForeground(1, new Notification());
}
```

Links below will give you a little more insight into Foreground Services.

https://blog.logimonk.com/post/foreground-service-in-android

https://medium.com/@debuggingisfun/android-o-work-around-background-service-limitation-e697b2192bc3

**Create your BroadcastReceiver from the service.**

Comment: Thank you, I did it but he things in Android Foreground service is killed by the Broadcast receiver because using the same thread, how can I achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63327282/forground-service-broadcast-reciver-in-android