# How to ignore Forground Service killed by Broadcast Reciver When both using same thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm creating an app. which is always wants to trigger when the phone call states changes (Phone state listener), but my **Broadcast receiver killed by Android after a few minutes So I created a Foreground service to keep the app running in the background**, but the thing is After I installed the app I start the foreground service in the MainActivity through button click, then if the broadcast receiver triggers my foreground service stops. I think `Service` and `Broadcast receiver` using the ***same thread*** I guess. How can I Archive that I below coding

> Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- This part is inside the application -->

        <service android:name=".HammerService" android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

> MainActivity

```
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         
            btn=findViewById(R.id.button);
           checkAndRequestPermissions();

          final Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, HammerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Call Hammer ");
        
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

                    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(MainActivity.this, serviceIntent);
                }
            }
        });
           
    
          }
        private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
     int readPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
     int read_call_log = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
    
     List listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    
     if (readPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
     }
    
     if (read_call_log != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
     }
    
     if (read_call_log != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS);
     }
    
     if (read_call_log != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
     }
    
     if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                 (String[]) listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                 REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    
         return false;
     }
     return true;
    }

> App

    public class App extends Application {
        public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
    
            createNotificationChannel();
    
        }
        private void createNotificationChannel() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    
                NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Example Service Channel",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                );
                NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    
            }
        }
    }
```

> HammerService

```
public class HammerService extends Service {
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                startMyOwnForeground();
            else
                startForeground(1, new Notification());
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private void startMyOwnForeground() {
          //  String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
            String channelName = "Call Hummer Background Service";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
    
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                    .setContentTitle("Call Hammer Service")
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .build();
            startForeground(2, notification);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0, notificationIntent, 0);
    
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("Call Hammer Service")
                    .setContentText(input)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();
    
            startForeground(1, notification);
    
            //do heavy work on a background thread
            //stopSelf();
    
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }   
   
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

> CallReciverclass

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    
            try {
    
                runfirstTime(context,intent);
                Toast.makeText(context, "1st", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
    
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
    
                }
            }
        }
      }
```