# Service dies even I created separate thread to the broadcast receiver which is inside the service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I'm creating an App to monitoring call logs and send them to the cloud(`Firebase Realtime database`). I created `Service` to alive the app. Inside the service class, I created a `Broadcast` receiver to monitor the phone call states. *I know about the background service restriction in android oreo and above*

1. First, I register the broadcast receiver like this

   ```
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
       filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);

       registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }
   ```

After that, I can able to see call state changes as toast messages.
but I try to save to the `firebase realtime database` inside the phone state listener class, My app background service stops. So I register the Broadcast receiver with a separate thread like below

```
@Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("ht");
    handlerThread.start();
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
    Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter, null, handler);

}
```

Even though My background service stops. **What went wrong here?**

Comment: have you read documentation about the restriction of background services in newer devices?

Comment: yes, I created foreground service to keep the service running in the background, see my full code here https://stackoverflow.com/q/63327282/5359340

Comment: If the `Service` stops, it is probably crashing. Check the logcat for exceptions/messages. Do not filter the logcat or you might miss something important. Post your crash with stacktrace here if you can't figure it out.